# Unable to use the FragmentContainerView class in AndroidStudio 4.0 Beta 1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have switched to Android studio 4.0 beta version , but evidently my app doesnot support **FragmentContainerView** class from **androidx** library . I have enabled **androidx** in **the gradle properties**. The stable version **Android Studio 3.6** supports it but not the beta version .Is this problem  due to local files or is it same across all devices?

This was the error displayed :

> Class referenced in the layout file,
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView, was not found in the
>   project or the libraries

Comment: update your gradle dependencies to `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0` (kotlin) or `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0` (java)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you meant by

> "enabled androidx in the gradle properties"

The following worked for me:

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

`build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    def nav_version = '2.2.2'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

on Android Studio 4.0.1